# How to match everything that is not in brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

if I have the following

```
the quick brown (fox jumped) over the (lazy) dog
```

I want a match that has

```
the quick brown over the dog
```

or a list of multiple matches

- `the quick brown`
- `over the`
- `dog`

and then I can stitch those strings together...

How to create a match that gets that?

I could do

```
(\(.*?\))
```

to find all the things that ARE in the brackets and then just use those strings to remove them from the original string, but I'd kind of like to achieve it all within a single regex ( that way the regex can be loaded as a setting, and there's no need to post process the string )

Comment: I think I could manage to do that having many matches, but in a single one I don't know. You can try something with `lookahead` and `lookbehind` http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @hwnd you deleted your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(?<!\([^\(\)]*).(?![^\(\)]*\))
```

To get a full combined string, try this:

```
string strRegex = @"(?<!\([^\(\)]*).(?![^\(\)]*\))";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"the quick brown (fox jumped) over the (lazy) dog";

var fullString = string.Concat((object[]) 
    myRegex.Matches(strTargetString).OfType<Match>().ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(fullString); // Produces "the quick brown  over the  dog"
```

If you need the multiple spaces converted into single spaces, try this:

```
string betterString = 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(fullString,@"\s+"," ");
Console.WriteLine(betterString); // Produces "the quick brown over the dog"
```

Comment: splits out each character, but would work nicely with it all stitch back together

Comment: @KeithNicholas - I provided you with an example!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test extensively, but this seems to work. (Multiple matches)

```
var str = "the quick brown (fox jumped) over the (lazy) dog";

var result = Regex.Matches(str,
    @"("
        + @"\s*\w+\s*"
        + @"(?<!\([^\(\)]*)(?![^\(\)]*\))"
    + ")+"
    , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// results (Matches)
// ^the quick brown $
// ^ over the $
// ^ dog$
```

Comment: only problem is it kills the white space.

Comment: @KeithNicholas hmm, check the edit, might work. I've placed `$` just to show where the match ends.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single regex to do it for the generic case. Regexs are for extracting a match, not the other way round.

If your goal is to remove the text inside some character such as ([< etc, then you could do a simple string replace, iterating over the answers:

```
var myRegex = "(\(.*?\))";
var myString = "the quick brown (fox jumped) over the (lazy) dog";
while (var match = regex.Match(myString, myRegex)) {
  myString.replace(match, "");
}
```

Or something like that! That way you can still select what the brackets are. This could be wrapped up in a method to make it cleaner for your code to use.

(That code should be taken as pseudo code, it's just hit Friday drinks time!)

Comment: That is not the point as he mentioned, and `Regex.Replace(str, @"\(.*?\)\s?", "");` would be far easier.

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what I'd do instead Bruno

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The point that I was making (badly) was that the stuff outside the brackets isn't a single match, but several matches. Even if you were to capture them, you'd still need to re-assemble the matches afterwards.

Comment: yes, that is a good point @chrisb,  for my purposes I think if I always stitched all the matches together into a single string, then what I need it for would work, I don't know what the regex is going to be necessarily, so far they have resulted in 1 match, so multiple matches stitched together wouldn't break anything